# how to use print attribute react-native-share

Tags: android, ios, react-native, printing, share

I am using the react-native-share extension for the share and print Pdf document. I am trying to add The 'Print' attribute but it is not working or I couldn't get it right
I follow this document https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-open#activitytype

and i used the example here https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-open#activityitemsources-ios-only
According to this document, I created an object like

```
const url = this.props.navigation.state.params.document.url
           {
            item:{
            print : url
            }
          },
```

[image]

Comment: share single/multiple images or pdf file using react-native-share, answer by me with more detailed info here, checkout  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016851/want-to-share-multiple-images-with-separate-caption-to-each-image-whatsapp-reac/67167916#67167916

Answer (score 2):

https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-remote-file

The code below solves my problem for IOS. I think there was a problem because the document came from the url.Its still not working for android

```
static sharePDFWithAndroid(fileUrl, type) {
  let filePath = null;
  let file_url_length = fileUrl.length;
  const configOptions = { fileCache: true };
  RNFetchBlob.config(configOptions)
    .fetch('GET', fileUrl)
    .then(resp => {
      filePath = resp.path();
      return resp.readFile('base64');
    })
    .then(async base64Data => {
      base64Data = `data:${type};base64,` + base64Data;
      await Share.open({ url: base64Data });
      // remove the image or pdf from device's storage
      await RNFS.unlink(filePath);
    });
}
```